# Create a user in Attask via REST API v3

Tags: php, attask

When I try to POST user creation request it requires username and password to authenticate, but then I need to provide username for the new user. I can't understand how to write correct request for my task.

I'm using StreamClient.php, when I try to create a user I need to send post request:

```
$client->post('user', array('username' => $user, 'firstname' => $f, 'lastname' => $l));
```

If someone could provide a working example, it would be very helpful.

Comment: Please show us the code for your current attempt

Comment: I'm using StreamClient.php, when I try to create a user I need to send post request:

$client->post('user', array('username' => $user, 'firstname' => $f, 'lasname' => $l));

Comment: I was trying to do many combinations, but all were unsuccessful((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont use username for the new user. You would use "emailAddr"
Try this:

YOURDOMAIN.attask/api/user?updates={"emailAddr":"test@test.com","password":"userpassword"}&method=post&username=USERNAME&password=PASSWORD

or if that does not work and you are using the StreamClient.php

You should be logging in not in the same POST. For Example you would login:

$login = $client->login('LOGIN_USERNAME', 'PASSWORD');

Look at the StreamClientSample.php, around line 37 //login. developers.attask.com/api-docs/code-samples

Let me know if that helps

Comment: I'm using StreamClient.php:<br/>
This part is successful:<br/>
$this->session = $this->client->login($this->cred['login'], $this->cred['password']);<br/>
but then I try to:<br/>
$result = $this->client->post('user', "emailAddr=test44@test.com&password=userpassword");<br/>
it returns:<br/>
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'StreamClientException' with message 'username cannot be null' in...<br/>
then :<br/>
$result = $this->client->post('user', 'username=' . $this->cred['login'] . '&password=' . $this->cred['password'] . "&emailAddr=test44@test.com&password=userpassword");<br/>

..the same result

Comment: Thanks, after few manipulations following example worked:
$this->client->post('user', array("emailAddr"=> "test44@test.com", "password" => "userpassword"));

Answer (score 0):

1. You will need to create an admin session first by making a POST method call. You will get a sessionID in the response.
2. Include the session id sessionID= to the user POST method you are making. You will also need to supply firstName or lastName. The user will be created, but not activated at this point.
3. You will then need to create a user token for the new user by executing restful call to api/user/assignUserToken by supplying the new user id (.../api/user/assignUserToken?id=).
4. Use the token to complete the user registration process by making PUT call to .../api/user/completeUserRegistration by supplying the user information and the token.